# C++ Win32 Padding zeros to an int via to_wstring

Tags: c++, winapi, wstring

I am trying to learn C++ Win32. I built a timer class for a game environment. Typical game timer and it works well. I have this function that I would like to display the current game time with.

```cpp
std::wstring Time::DisplayGameTime()
{
    std::wstring Label = L"Current Time: ";

    std::wstring daysText = L" " + std::to_wstring(Days()); //Returns int
    std::wstring monthsText = L", " + std::to_wstring(Months()); //Returns int
    std::wstring yearsText = L", " + std::to_wstring(Years()); // Returns int
    std::wstring hoursText = L" " + std::to_wstring(Hours()); // Returns int
    std::wstring minutesText = L" : " + std::to_wstring(Minutes()); // Returns int

    std::wstring message = Label + daysText + monthsText + yearsText + hoursText + minutesText;
    return message;
}
```

This works well too, except the minutes integer only prints one digit until it reaches 10. I would like to pad a leading zero to it like you would find in a normal time clock. Since I am using std::to_wstring, I cannot use format specifiers like in a swprintf_s buffer. I have tried to figure out how to use a wstringstream for this but none of what I've tried has worked.

The goal is to use this function to convert to LPCWSTR later on for DrawText to display to the Window.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't use `snwprintf_s`?

Comment: C++ does not allow arrays to be returned. I've already tried returning a wchar_t* but whenever I call DrawTextW I end up getting Chinese characters displayed.

Comment: @DaBigBoy: True, but you can keep the array local, and pass it to the constructor of `std::wstring`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the traditional imperative "brute-force" way of solving this:

```cpp
int DaysVal = Days();
std::wstring W = (DaysVal < 10 ? L"0" : L"") + std::to_wstring(DaysVal);
```

Or.. use `std::stringstream` with `std::setw` and `std::setfill` (from `<iomanip>`).

```cpp
std::wstringstream WS;
WS << std::setw(2) << std::setfill(L'0') << Days();
std::wstring W = WS.str();
```

PS: Features from `<iomanip>` also work on `std::cout` and other streams, so  `std::(w)stringstream` is unnecessary with I/O!

EDIT: And if someone's looking for a solution utilizing `snprintf()`:

```cpp
char CB[128];
std::snprintf(CB, sizeof(CB), "%.*i", NumDigits, Num);
```

Using precision (`%.*i`) is superior to using width (`%*i`), since the second one operates on total of characters and not number of digits!

EDIT(2): To be future-proof, I'm also including a solution using `std::format()`:

I haven't played with [{fmt}](https://fmt.dev) for too long, so I have no idea how to achieve the same result as with `printf()`. For now, it should suffice (but expect to have one digit less with negative numbers):

```cpp
std::wstring W = fmt::format(L"{:+0{}}", Num, NumDigits);
```

Comment: The stream library in C++ has one of the worst interfaces, and is one of worst performing across all platforms. Luckily, there's no need to use it anymore with C++20. It comes with a real [formatting library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format).

Comment: @IInspectable Right, I will add a solution utilizing std::format. I also very much dislike the stream library, but I included it since it was the "idiomatic" way to handle such tasks.

Comment: wstringstream worked the best for me. Got the zero padding that I needed, now looks like an actual timer. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Writing your output to a `std::wstringstream` object is very similar to writing to the `std::wcout` stream; you use consecutive calls to the `<<` operator; then, when you are finished, you can get a copy of the underlying `wstring` object using the [`.str()` member function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream/str).

You can control the width and padding character for each field, individually, using the [`std::setw`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setw) and [`std::setfill`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setfill) functions – you can put calls to these, if required, before each field whose output you want to adjust.

In your case, you can use the default formats for all fields except the last, where you would set the width to 2 and the fill character to `L'0'`:

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

std::wstring Time::DisplayGameTime()
{
    std::wstringstream message;
    message
        << L"Current Time: "
        // D,M,Y,H using default format ...
        << L" " << Days()
        << L", " << Months()
        << L", " << Years()
        << L" " << Hours()
        // Add Minute using zero-padded, fixed width of 2 ...
        << L" : " << std::setw(2) << std::setfill(L'0') << Minutes();
    return message.str();
}
```

Comment: Perfect. Worked like a charm. Normally don't use set and setfill(a bit confusing) but I get the zero padding that I needed. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

As you discovered, [`to_wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) doesn't allow you to provide formatting options. If you want to keep using `to_wstring` you'll have to apply the formatting yourself. There are many options to do so, so I'll just pick one at random:

- Always prepend a `"0"`
- Then return the right-most 2 digits

Something like this:

```cpp
auto const minutesText = []() {
    // Always prepend a "0"
    auto const minute { L"0" + std::to_wstring(Minutes()) };
    // Return the right-most 2 digits
    return minute.substr(minute.length() - 2);
}();
```

If you can use C++20 things are far easier, and usually a *lot* faster, too. C++20 introduced a [formatting library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) that combines a succinct formatting description language (similar to Python's) with the type safety of C++' I/O streams.

It makes the following implementation possible:

```cpp
#include <format>

std::wstring Time::DisplayGameTime()
{
    return std::format(L"Current Time:  {}, {}, {} {} : {:02}",
                       Days(), Months(), Years(),
                       Hours(), Minutes());
}
```

[`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) is similar to the `printf` family of functions in taking a formatting string, plus zero or more arguments to be interpolated. The formatting string describes the final output as well as where the arguments are placed and how they are formatted.

The first four placeholders do not contain any [formatting specification](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Standard_format_specification), and produce results similar to what `to_wstring` would have. The final placeholder `{:02}` encodes both the field width (`2`) as well as the fill character (`0`) to use when the output doesn't produce enough characters. It could have been spelled `{:0>2}` to specify right-aligned text, but that is the default integer values so I omitted it.

Using the C++20 formatting library requires a C++20 compiler (that implements it). Visual Studio 2019 and Visual Studio 2022 do. Either one requires setting the [`/std:c++-latest`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/std-specify-language-standard-version) compiler option. At this time, the C++20 formatting library does not appear under the `/std:c++20` compiler option. The [C++ Language Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/c-cpp-prop-page#c-language-standard) can be set from the IDE as well.

---

**Bonus material:** [Why does std::format do that? - Charlie Barto - CppCon 2021](https://youtu.be/zssTF1uhxtM): A look at Microsoft's implementation that—among other things—explains why `std::format` is orders of magnitude faster than I/O streams. This is not introductory material.